# Modifying app.config at runtime throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I'm using `app.config` file to store and read some parameters (sql server instance name, user, password, log directory, etc). Now, I need to modify some parameters which depends of user and managed this but only if I run `.exe` from bin/release directory.

When I create setup and install my aplication I'm not able to change this parameters - it throws `TargetInvocationException`. I've tried to run my app as administrator but without success.

The code which I currently use is the following:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("username");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("username", this.Config.Username);
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

I've tried a few other solutions found on stackoverflow but without success.

Comment: when you run the code that you have what is the value of this.Config.Username.. ??

Comment: This is a pretty classic UAC trap.  You can modify the file when you debug your program on your dev machine but it can't work after you install it.  Files in `c:\program files` are not writable.  You'll need a separate program that edits the file so it can ask for UAC elevation.  Or not use settings to store this info, an .xml file in AppData works too.

Comment: @DJKRAZE value of Username is valid. reading works.

Comment: @HansPassant I'll try with separate program, or using xml file

Comment: also if you don't like that way ..look at using XPATH to do it as well

Comment: i've created separate program - it works, for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally we cannot modify config entries when application is running.

When you ran the exe from bin, it didn't modify the *.exe.config .

instead it modified ***.vshost.exe.Config** file.

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None); returns reference to *.vshost.exe.Config  file
```

*.exe.config is read only, you cannot update this file.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
 // update SaveBeforeExit
 settings[username].Value = "newkeyvalue"; //how are you getting this.Config.Username
  ...
 //save the file
 config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
 //relaod the section you modified
 ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
```

Here are some Steps to Follow For example if I wanted to modify a setting based on DateTime value.. this simple explanation should make it easy for you to follow.

```
 1: // Open App.Config of executable   
 2: System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);   
 3: // Add an Application Setting.   
 4: config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("LastDateChecked");   
 5: config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("LastDateChecked", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());   
 6: // Save the configuration file.   
 7: config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);   
 8: // Force a reload of a changed section.   
 9: ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```